# geocode in ggmap can't connect to google map API (R)

Tags: geocode, ggmap

Hi `geocode` worked for me before but not now.

```
> install.packages("ggmap")
> library(ggmap)
> geocode('boston ma')
Information from URL : http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/maps/api/geocode/json?address=boston%20ma&sensor=false
  lon lat
1  NA  NA
Warning messages:
1: In readLines(connect, warn = FALSE) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
2: In geocode("boston ma") :   geocoding failed for "boston ma".
  if accompanied by 500 Internal Server Error with using dsk, try google.
```

I updated R and `ggmap`... Can somebody help please... Thanks 
(I'm not sure it was `http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org` before - did it change?)

Comment: If you specify `source`, you can get lon/lat. `geocode("houston texas", source = "google")`. It seems that just specifying a location is not good enough now.

Comment: works! thanks a lot @jazzurro